# PHP foreach Loop Adds Variables Together Automatically

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I have a PHP loop which seems to be adding or storing data somehow which isn't relevant and from the last value of the array it interprets and then echos out as a bit of a mess. Here is my code:

```
$filenamewithext = explode("\n", $_POST['filename']);
foreach($filenamewithext as $line)
{   
    $filename = mysql_real_escape_string($line);
    $fileletter = substr($filename, 0, 1);
        if (ctype_alpha($fileletter)) {
            $folder = $folder.$fileletter."/";
        } else {
            $folder = $folder. "0-9" . "/";
        }   
    echo $folder;

}
```

It outputs something like this given that we had $filenamewithtext = test1, test2 and test3 based on what the POST data is which is a HTML Text Area and an array is created with each new line being a new value.

Output:

> /foldername/t//foldername/t/t/foldername/t/t/t/

What I need is it to just have the the 1 "t" every time instead of the first character being repeated every-time. I have been trying to work this out for quite some time now and any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

UPDATE:

Code used to initiate $folder variable.

```
if (array_key_exists('submit', $_POST)) {
$cat = $_POST['selectCat'];
switch ($cat){
    case "Adult" : 
        $tablename = "voxadultfilestable" ;
        $folder = "/imagesxxx/" ;
        break;
    case "clips" : 
        $tablename = "voxfilestable";
        $folder = "/images/" ;
        break;
    case "concerts" :
        $tablename = "voxconcertsfilestable";
        $folder = "/imagesconcerts/" ;          
        break;
    case "mixes" : 
        $tablename = "voxmixesfilestable";
        $folder = "/imagesmixes/"   ;       
        break;
    case "movies" : 
        $tablename = "voxmoviesfilestable";
        $folder = "/imagesmovies/"  ;
        break;
    case "mp3" : 
        $tablename = "voxmp3filestable";
        $folder = "/imagesmp3/" ;
        break;
}
```

Comment: what is `$line` in `$filename1 = mysql_real_escape_string($line);`

Comment: Sorry $line isn't the correct code it should be $filenamewithext. I have edited the original question.

Comment: mistake in `foreach($filenamewithext as $filenamewithext)` line `$filenamewithext` same

Comment: it should not same should like this `foreach($filenamewithext as $newtext)`

Comment: I have updated the code and the issue still persists. Thanks for the advice though.

Comment: what is you expected result? and what you are entering in text area ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to add

```
$folder = '';
```

inside foreach loop starts. It looks that

$folder = $folder.$fileletter."/";
is adding old $folder and returning to $folder

Try it

```
$filenamewithext = explode("\n", $_POST['filename']);
foreach($filenamewithext as $line)
{   
    $folder = ''; // empty $folder at beginning of loop
    $filename = mysql_real_escape_string($line);
    $fileletter = substr($filename, 0, 1);
        if (ctype_alpha($fileletter)) {
            $folder = $folder.$fileletter."/";
        } else {
            $folder = $folder. "0-9" . "/";
        }   
    echo $folder;

}
```

Comment: Thanks, it wasn't quite the right answer but you helped me a lot. It turns out I needed to set $folder = $category which was a static string I created each time the loop was executed. Thanks again and I'am glad I finally solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is because your foreach is looping through a variable and declaring a variable with the same name:

```
foreach($filenamewithext as $filenamewithext)
```

Change that to something like

```
foreach($filenamewithext as $fext) {
}
```

Edit, what is `$filename1` and `$folder`?  You keep appending to `$folder`.  Reset it at the top of the loop.

Comment: I have updated the code an the issue still persists. Thanks for the advice though.

Comment: I have added that to the main post. It basically defines it based on another piece of data sent to the file through POST.